# how to detect when page scrolled to bottom and execute a function ONE time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using ajax to dynamically load XML from a web service, the returned records are limited to just 25 items for each url 'load' or 'call'.... to work around that I have a process whereby the user scrolls down the page and when they reach 90% of the page height (or when  they reach page bottom - not sure which I'll choose yet), a variable named startindexnum is incremented by 25.

so startindexnum starts out at 25... then  after the first 'fire' of the function, the startindexnum becomes 50, on the 3rd it becomes 75, etc. etc.

my problem is that it fires multiple times and is somewhat erratic - processing multiple times when I scroll to the bottom and increasing by MORE than 25 sometimes (no doubt a result of running multiple times I think).

anyone have any idea what I need to tweak to get this to correctly generate the incremental startindex variable to append to my ajax URL where Im retrieving XML?  thanks.

```
var scrollcount = 1;
var startindexnum = 25;
var processing;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(e){
       if (processing)
            return false;

            window.onscroll = function(ev) {

             if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight){
                //if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.9){
                    // you're at x%  of the page
                    processing = true;
                    scrollcount = scrollcount + 1;
                    startindexnum = scrollcount * startindexnum;
                    console.log(scrollcount);
                    docall();

                    processing = false;

                };
            };
    });
});
```

Comment: tried using unbind() ? After the table has been rendered again - bind the ,method again ?

Comment: btw .. why do you have window.onscroll and $document.scroll ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is I am betting `docall()` is an asynchronous call, so setting of `processing` to `false` after that call does nothing to block the future scroll events.

The setting of false is happening before the results are returned. You want to set `processing` back to false when `docall()` is done doing its task.

```
         if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight){
            //if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.9){
                // you're at x%  of the page
                processing = true;
                scrollcount = scrollcount + 1;
                startindexnum = scrollcount * startindexnum;
                console.log(scrollcount);
                docall();

                //processing = false;  <--get rid of this

            };
```

and

```
function docall(){

    //When you are done fetching the new data and update the page set 
    function AjaxCallIsDone() {
        processing = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this is right on track.... still not behaving quite as I need it to though - Im going to tinker with it more.  thanks for your feedback - I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to epascarello's post...

you don't need the $(document).scroll(fn) and the window.onscroll, which you are attaching to every time your document scroll handler is executed.  A few things:

1) Firstly, take a look at this scroll post by John Resig. [Scrolling by J.Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/)

2) If you want the jquery method then use window instead of document $(window).scroll(fn).

3) If not then I think the following will work for you:

```
var scrollcount = 1;
var startindexnum = 25;
var processing;

$(document).ready(function(){
    window.onscroll = function(ev) {
        if (!processing) {   
            if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight){
                processing = true;
                scrollcount = scrollcount + 1;
                startindexnum = scrollcount * startindexnum;
                console.log(scrollcount);
                docall();
            }
        }               
    }
});
```

Comment: i changed the ajax call so its non-Asynchronous,

    $.ajax({
      async: false,

(I will go research any unforseen negative effects of it though since at the moment none come to mind)

and it dawned on me that part of the erratic behavior (where the math was way off) was due to the fact that this line:

    startindexnum = scrollcount * startindexnum;

had to be hardcoded to use 25 (the default increment of returned items in the api), so it looked like:

    startindexnum = scrollcount * 25;

thanks to all.